# grep results in array

Tags: arrays, bash, grep

I have a document which contains several names of files over which I want to use grep to gather all files with the xsd extension. When I use grep with my regex pattern, I get the correct results, about 18 of them. Now I want to store these results in an array. I used the following bash code :

```
targets=($(grep -i "AppointmentManagementService[\.]" AppointmentManagementService\?wsdl))
```

Then I print the array size :

```
echo ${#targets[@]}
```

which turns out to be 80 instead of 18 since it stored only a part of one result into an array cell. How do I make sure only one result goes into one array cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The results probably get split over multiple cells because a character (most likely space) is interpreted as an internal field separator.

Try executing it like this:

```
IFS=$'\n' targets=($(grep -i "AppointmentManagementService[\.]" AppointmentManagementService\?wsdl))
```